# What does a browser do when there's a javascript src file that isn't cached?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

Does it send an HTTP GET request for the specified file? I'm trying to write my own NodeJS webserver, and want to know how to go about dealing with sending the browser the javascript files it needs.

Let's say I'm using several javascript libraries for a web-app I'm building, and for each of them I have a script tag in the head of my HTML file (e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`). In my server, would I be able to code something up to call different functions based off of the src requested, and to return a file that isn't necessarily in the same location that the HTML would make one expect it to be?

I'm still new to NodeJS and webservers in general, so I apologize if this is really obvious to other people out there...

Comment: Why the head (and not at the bottom of the page where it's supposed to be)?

Comment: *"and to return a file that isn't necessarily in the same location that the HTML would make one expect it to be?"* - I'm having trouble understanding this. Could someone confirm that this is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it send an HTTP GET request for the specified file?

Yes.

> I'm trying to write my own NodeJS webserver, and want to know how to go about dealing with sending the browser the javascript files it needs.

Then don't worry about how the browser decides what HTTP requests to make. Just implement the HTTP specification.

> In my server, would I be able to code something up to call different functions based off of the src requested, and to return a file that isn't necessarily in the same location that the HTML would make one expect it to be?

This sounds like you are planning to serve up different content for the same URI based on the referer header … I'd expect this to hit a cache and turn into a race condition based nightmare. Don't do it. Write your HTML so if you need different scripts, you request them from different URIs.

If, on the other hand, you mean that you want to return data without reading it out of a file on the file system, then that is fine. Clients don't care how the server determined what data to put in an HTTP response. Just make sure that it is sane and consistent.

Comment: No I'm planning on serving up the same content for the same URI, it just won't necessarily be in the same location as the URI might make it sound. i.e. if the browser is requesting a script where src='jquery.js', the file itself might actually be located at 'files/javascript/jquery.js'. Does that sound like it'll be problematic?          One more question for the noob in me: If I get an HTTP GET request for a URI like above, what will it look like on the server? Would it appear to my server as if a browser is requesting the page url.com/jquery.js?

Comment: As I said. It doesn't matter how the server determines what the content of the response is. The client has no idea. (Well, it does matter, but only in so far as you want the server to be easy to maintain).

Comment: An HTTP request is an HTTP request. There is usually nothing to distinguish a request for an HTML document from one for an image, script, etc, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. My confusion is in that I'm dealing with everything related to server technology for the first time here. Everything I've done so far has been client-side, so to me an HTTP request was just something I sent off and then hopefully ended up with what I wanted.

Comment: And you're starting out by writing your own HTTP server? Welcome to the deep end.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it send an HTTP GET request for the specified file?

Yes.

You don't have to worry about when and how the resources are requested from the browser, just map the resource addresses that you want to make available to the content that you want to return for each resource.

> would I be able to code something up to call different functions based off of the src requested, and to return a file that isn't necessarily in the same location that the HTML would make one expect it to be?

Of course. There is no direct relation between the address of a resource and the physical file where you get the data for the resource, there is always some code that does the mapping between the resource address and where the data is fetched. It's just easier to manage resources when the files are arranged in basically the same hierarchy as the resource addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
Does it send an HTTP GET request for the specified file?
```

As Quentin said, Yes the browser will request each script file specified in the source HTML with a GET request for that particular URI.

When your web server receives that GET request, you can do anything you want to return data for the URI request.  You do not have to actually return a file from that path.  In fact, you can parse out the path and use the different parts of the path as data parameters in the request (that's what a lot of web apps do these days).

So, if the request comes in for `http://www.mysite.com/user/john/accountnumber`, you could look up in your database and fetch the account number for a user named `"john"` and return that data.  The result does not have to come from an actual file or from anything that actually has that path.